# '+' cannot add two pointers, but just printing an int and an explicit string?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I am trying to use an array to keep track of the totals of different types of items (up to 50 types). When I want to print the totals  out, I get an error saying "'+' cannot add two pointers." I'm thinking the problem is with my totals array somehow, but I can't figure it out. Below is a sample of my code:

```
  string printSolution()
  {
  int totals[50];

  string printableSolution = "";

  for (int k = 0; k < itemTypeCount; k++)
  {
      totals[k] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
  {
      totals[items[i].typeCode]++;
  }

  for (int a = 0; a < itemTypeCount; a++)
  {
      printableSolution.append("There are " + totals[a] + " of Item type " + (a + 1) + ". \n");
  }


}
```

Comment: Wrap the `"There are"` with a `std::string` or use a `std::stringstream`. Right now you're adding `char*` with `int`.

Comment: When you're working with C-style strings, you have to use `strcat()` to concatenate them. `+` only works with `std::string`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot add two pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108965/error-cannot-add-two-pointers) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16324599/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18580262/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844986/103167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
"There are " + totals[a] + " of Item type " + (a + 1) + ". \n"
```

It means `char* + int + char* + int + char*`. You need to print them out separately or change the `int` to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The string literals `"Foo"` are of `const char*`, i.e. pointer type.

To understand what happens with:

```
"There are " + totals[a] + " of Item type " + (a + 1) + ". \n"
```

Let's look at an expression:

```
"0123456789" + 5
```

This actually just offsets 5 bytes from the start, so becomes:

```
"56789"
```

So an expression:

```
"0123456789" + 5 + "foo"
```

becomes:

```
"56789" + "foo"
```

as pointers, and this is not defined.

What you really want is string concatenation; this can be achieved using `std::string`.

We can write:

```
   std::string("56789") + "foo"
```

and this generates a `std::string` with value: `"56789foo"` as you desire.

But:

```
 std::string("0123456789") + 5
```

is also not defined. You need to use:

```
std::string("0123456789") + std::to_string(5)
```

So, finally you want:

```
std::string("There are ") + std::to_string(totals[a]) + " of Item type " + std::to_string(a + 1) + ". \n"
```

Note now you do not need to explitly convert all the `""` to `std:string`, as once you have one implicit type conversion will take care of the other operand in `operator+`. However, adding them would do no harm:

```
std::string("There are ") + std::to_string(totals[a]) + std::string(" of Item type ") + std::to_string(a + 1) + std::string(". \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use C++-style formatting instead:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "There are " << totals[a] << " of Item type " << (a + 1) << ". \n";
printableSolution += oss.str();
```